# Unable to obtain instance of HTTP request in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am having trouble retrieving form values using the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class.

I have an endpoint that creates a product and another that updates it set up  like this

```
Route::post('products', 'ProductController@store');

Route::put('products/{product}', 'ProductController@update');
```

The `store` and `update` methods in the `ProductController` are

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate inputs
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'category'  => 'required',
        'status'    => 'required',
        'price'     => 'required',
        'image'     => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg',
        'interest'  => 'required'
    ]);

    // return 401 response if validation fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    // create & store the product
    if ($product = Product::create([
        'name'      => $request->name,
        'category'  => $request->category,
        'status'    => $request->status,
        'price'     => $request->price,
        'interest'  => $request->interest,
    ])) {
        // store the product image
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $destinationPath = "public/images/products";
        $filename = 'pramopro_' . $product->name . '_' . $product->id . '.' . $file->extension();

        Storage::putFileAs($destinationPath, $file, $filename);

        ProductImage::create([
            'product_id'    => $product->id,
            'name'          => $filename
        ]);
    }

    // return new product
    return new ProductResource($product);
}

public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    // dd($request);

    // validate inputs
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'category'  => 'required',
        'status'    => 'required',
        'price'     => 'required',
        'image'     => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg',
        'interest'  => 'required'
    ]);

    // return 401 response if validation fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    // update this product
    if ($product) {
        $product->update($request->all());

        return new ProductResource($product);
    } else {
        return response()->json(["error" => "Not found"], 404);
    }
}
```

Now when I test the endpoints in postman, I can successfully create a new product record. But if I try to update a product, I get a `401 unauthorized` error even though all the required fields are filled. `dd($request)`returns null but `dd($product)` returns the product as expected.

Maybe I have been looking at it so hard so I have missed something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you receive any specific errors with the 401 in regard to validation?  Are you sure your `put` route isn't in an `auth` middleware group?

Comment: Both the store & update routes are not guarded by the auth middleware. It simply returns the all the field names saying they are required. 401 is actually validation error but I'm supplying all fields same way I did for the create

Comment: And you're certain you are passing a brand new set of parameters with Postman?  They aren't unchecked and you 
have it set to PUT?

Comment: I am double sure

Comment: Are you sure you haven't defined this route twice?

Comment: @matticustard no route has been defined twice. I have double checked that

Comment: Php and Laravel do not understand PUT requests unless you specify a hidden input in the request with the name `_method` and the value `PUT`.

Comment: @RazvanToader I changed my route to `POST` and the update works fine. I did that because its an API route

Answer (score 0):

This is the reasons I think why the `$request` return null

- The store and update request is same name. Two input name or select name or textarea name can't be the same name in the same web page. If its same it will always get the first one that is the reason why it is returning null because the first one is empty.
- The name you're calling is incorrect

Hope it helps!